# Release Heroku container with Platform API

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, heroku-api

I'm trying to release a web process into a container by using only the API and not the Heroku CLI.

I know that i can do something like `heroku container:release web -a <<myApp>>`, but use the Heroku CLI is not an option since i'm trying to create a GH Action to do it.

After pushing correctly the image in the heroku registry, i tried to release the container doing as stated from the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) in the following way:

```
curl -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP/formation \
            -d '{
            "updates": [
              {
                "type": "web",
                "docker_image": "$(docker inspect $IMAGE --format={{.Id}})"
              }
            ]
          }' \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3.docker-releases" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $HEROKU_API_KEY"
```

However it keeps giving me the same message:

```
{
  "resource": "docker_image",
  "id": "not_found",
  "message": "Couldn't find that docker image."
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

**NOTES**:

In my GH Action i already tried doing `heroku login -i` and passing username and access token, but it keeps giving me `Password: invalid option -s`.

Even if i copy the `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable, doing `docker push ...` fails.

Copying a valid .netrc file fails too with the same error of using the `HEROKU_API_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets stuck like me in this i'm posting another solution here.

Create the most simple `heroku.yml` in your repository.

Put the following content inside it:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

For me, there's no need for run section, since the CMD into the Dockerfile is already what i need to get executed.

In this way, heroku platform understand that must build the image and runs the container after the build process has completed